# Any examples of handling a recaptcha POST response?

Tags: perl, response, recaptcha

Current version V2 reCaptcha returns a "POST" in CGI:params.  Not exactly what the old V2 version did.

The up side is that any HTML form contents and the reCaptcha response come in at the same time.  The down side is that the "g-recaptcha-response" value is a blob that requires local validation.

The "g-recaptcha-response" value looks something like this:

```
03AJzQf7OU1j33-wm7I73BItJg-l2COD-YwSjesvfej_5vy5c0r_LUhaDU1KsvU0BV0Rc-MHRbR4L17TNya1CqFtCJGulzvwTpKCfjwWcwqj2e3nFiqeropkXnYzwE78Eydr0jGi3OjZCKK71rmhOXZr0OA_nC8Cpd6aPaexqkrfLXdiXFPE7pQqc-qixYzVklb2MIuPyxw414kVbyHsbDr5p-pitK9cXvvPYK1Td7T_z6xnMUIuNN5zY3ArYzlAGexsSffucQRrzSKT_779In1QzwQppASux3-Z_xPLQgCLnRsJlwcby7gFFWXHSfAxV2ErpsiGWQcGa1
```

How can one decipher this response in Perl to be sure it is a genuine acknowledgement that the Turing test was solved correctly?

Comment: Did you look here? https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify If so, what part of this check-verify loop is not working for you?

Comment: At least in my context the entire thing cited doesn't make sense. The server SSI doesn't run Java or JavaScript(?).  Is there a working example of of evaluating this "g-recaptcha-response" when constrained to use Perl?

Comment: That link is reasonably language agnostic so I'm not sure what you mean. My naive reading is that you have to submit the response you get (in any of a few ways) to another endpoint. The response from that gives you a boolean for success.

Comment: I want to validate Google's response at the server.  On the server, after dredging through CGI::params, I have a Perl $g-recaptcha-response variable that contains Google's response. How then do I evaluate the response in the same Perl script?

Comment: I have no idea. But you show a "g-recaptcha-response" you got from somewhere. According to that API docs, this has to be POSTed to an endpoint to get some JSON that has a flag in it. If you are doing something very different from this, you should make that clear in the description. All I see is you got a string from somewhere and need to validate it...

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the module [Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2](http://search.cpan.org/~pattawan/Captcha-reCAPTCHA-V2-0.3/lib/Captcha/reCAPTCHA/V2.pm)? I have succesfully used it and it is a great time saver. In plain CGI, the server side code that does the validation would look like:

```
my $rc = Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2->new;
my $result = $rc->verify('<your secret key here>', param('g-recaptcha-response'), remote_host);

# Check the result
if( !$result->{success} ){
  # The check failed, ignore the POST
  next;
}
```

I assume that you have already created your [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha) keys, have your HTML form and an idea of how to create the rest of the server side code.

To help other people that may seek how to do this, this is a minimum form for the client side (this is based on bootstrap):

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Comments</label>
                <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your comments..." rows="4" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div align="center">
                <button
                        class="g-recaptcha"
                        data-sitekey="<your site key here>"
                        data-callback="onSubmit">
                        Enviar mensaje
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("contact-form").submit();
  }
</script>
```

Then, on the server side you would need something like (this is based on FastCGI; for CGI you would not use the loop):

```
use CGI::Fast qw(:standard);
use Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2;

...

while(my $query = new CGI::Fast) {

  ...

  if( request_method eq 'POST' ) {

    my $rc = Captcha::reCAPTCHA::V2->new;
    my $result = $rc->verify('<your secret key here>', param('g-recaptcha-response'), remote_host);

    # Check the result
    if( !$result->{success} ){
      # The check failed, ignore the POST
      next;
    }

    # Do something with the form

  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Javier!  It's precisely the information needed. Ms. Kaewduangdee's useful CPAN contribution does a nice job!